# How to call a function after javascript async function with promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird, ecmascript-5

So I have a function where I'm chaining promises to fetch different data which would be like this.

```
that = this;    
that.load = function load() {
getEmployeeDetails(id)
    .then(function() {
        return validateEmployeeDetails([name, age, address]);
    })
    .spread(function (nameData, ageData, addressData) {
    that.name = "Name: " + nameData;
    that.age = "Age: " + ageData;
    that.address = "Address: " + addressData;
    })
    .then(function() {
        return someService.getDesignation(id);
    })
    .then(function(desig) {
        that.designation = desig;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        throw error;
    })
    .done();
};
```

I've another function where I have to call the load function

```
that.openEmployee = function openEmployee() {
    getEmployeeSession()
    .then(function getSessionData(res) {
        if(res.status === 200) {
            doSomething();
        }
    })
    .catch(function() {
        throw error;
    })
    .done();
};
```

Now I have to call the load function before the doSomething function. I tried using promises and also using events. But the problem is, it executes the spread part of the load and then calls the doSomething and then goes on executing the then blocks in load function. Whereas, I want to call the doSomething method after the last then in the load function is executed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop the pointless `.catch(function() {
        throw error;
    })`!

Comment: What promise library are you using that still has a `.done()` method?

Comment: What `doSomething` function are you talking about, do you mean `openEmployee`? And where does that call `load`?

Comment: Your `load` method needs to `return` the promise (and not call `.done()`), so that the caller of `load()` can chain onto it. @vmrvictor No, don't pass a callback.

Comment: The load function is used in other parts of the controller, so I cannot give doSomething as a callback to load as it has to be called only when openEmployee is called.

Comment: I cannot modify the load function as other part of the code is dependent on it

Comment: Other parts of the code depend on that the `load` function returns `undefined`? Even so, then write a second function `loadPromise` which `doSomething` can call directly, and `load` will become just `function() { loadPromise().done(); }`.

Comment: If you can't return a promise from the `load` method, try to use a global `flag` variable which will indicate the completion of the function call and use `setInterval` to check the status and call the `doSomething` method once you have the correct value of the `flag`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for that. I think that should work.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! It worked.